# How to secure a new MVC5 app with Azure ACS

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm trying to configure a new MVC5 application using an Azure ACS, but I'm not having much luck wiring up my project to the federation endpoint.

I started by creating a ACS (namespace, idp, and a RP).  The URI of my RP is: `http://localhost/ACSDemo.`  the federation metadata endpoint url is 
`https://hmhacsdemo.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml`

In VS (2013) I create a new web application, select MVC and change the authentication options to "Organizational Accounts" specify the type as "On-Premises", and supply my metdata url and app URI and click ok.

Click OK to create the project.  VS spins a little and then I see my solution.  In the web.config I find the following appsettings:

```
 <add key="ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint" value="https://hmhacsdemo.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
 <add key="ida:Audience" value="http://localhost/ACSDemo" />
```

but there is no other config sections that refer to identity in my web.config.

Next I go to the Home controller and defend the endpoint by placing an "Authorize" attribute on the controller class

```
 [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

However when I attempt the browse the website (pressing f5 in VS), I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Most likely causes:
The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request.

Things you can try:
Check the failed request tracing logs for additional information about this error. For more information, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler
Error Code     0x00000000
```

Its acting as though it has no notion of how it is supposed to authenticate its resources.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the wizard dies without stating any issue unless you're running VS as an admin.

I've repeated the above steps, this time launching VS2013 as an admin, and the authorization wizard adds the necessary configuration to my project.